# Time-based skydome change for Compiz Cube + KDE?

Tags: compiz, kde

I'm trying to find a way to automatically switch skydome 'wallpapers' for Compiz Cube based on time, say ten minutes. Having each of my desktops use a different one would be bonus internets.

Any help would be awesomely appreciated.

Edit: In case anyone's interested, here's a small script you can run from cron.

```
#!/bin/bash
pic=/your/background/directory 
newbg="$(ls $pic | shuf -n1)"
dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.freedesktop.compiz /org/freedesktop/compiz/cube/screen0/skydome_image org.freedesktop.compiz.set string:"$pic$newbg"
```

See http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Dbus

Comment: Was there a reason for removing Kubuntu from my title, other than the fact that Compiz is available for both? I thought it was pretty appropriate considering that I'm running Kubuntu.

Comment: This site uses tags to identify different Ubuntu releases and desktop environments, and the convention is to avoid duplicating this information in question titles whenever possible. It helps keep the site more readable.

Comment: I can understand tags, since I'm from SO, but I figured since this was KDE-specific it needed to be pointed out as such, as there are easier ways to do this from Gnome. In the end I obviously decided to point out "KDE" since that was the discerning part and maybe people with Ubuntu are using KDE (why I have no idea haha).

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyways or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reasons why you want it open. Regards